# Are Openconfig and Openflow trying to address same problem .?

Tags: openflow

I'm new to the networking world and come across these two words, Openconfig / Openflow are they trying to address same issue In traditional networking? or could anyone explain the basic difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In part.

OpenConfig is an initiative to use a vendor-neutral, common set of command and data models across a mixed-vendor network.

OpenFlow allows forwarding-plane control and is normally used in software-defined networks.

Both strive to make a network more transparent and more manageable. The big difference is that devices managed by OpenConfig still look and act like distinct devices. SDN tries to integrate all your hardware into a single, virtual device.